# Show on which columns duplicate rows, with respect to one column, differ

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe with arount one million rows and 500 columns.
I used the following code to find out how many rows are duplicates with respect to x:
`duplicate_x = df[df.duplicated(['x'])] print(len(duplicate_x))`
That gives 26.000 duplicates.

I used the following code to find out how many rows are duplicates with respect to all columns:
`duplicates = df[df.duplicated()] print(len(duplicates))`
That gives duplicates.

Now i would like to find out on which columns those 26.000 duplicates with respect to x differ: any ideas?
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `set(df[df.duplicated()].columns).difference('x')` ?

Comment: This is rather broad for a SO question. What do you want to know per duplicate on `x`: the number of distinct values per (other) column, the values that are equal the the first duplicate, or ...?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.